# Excel Formula Challenge

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a fairly specific Excel problem and I am hoping someone is savvy enough to come up with a working formula for me.  I am using Excel 2011 for Mac btw.

So, I have a list of about 134 ISBNS, for those who are unfamiliar, they all basically have the format 9781612803990 (13 digits beginning with 978) - All of these ISBNs are in one column.  To the right of this column is another list of ISBNS with extensions 978513440313-cover.pdf and 978513440313-text.pdf.  Obviously, the cover extension means I have a cover file for the ISBN and the text extension means I have the interior text file for the ISBN.  There are only 186 entries for this column.  This means I am missing a lot of files for some of the ISBNS because it should be exactly 2x of the first column.

First part of the problem is that I want to cross reference the ISBN columns so that I know exactly which files are missing and which ones I have.  That means (I'm assuming) we need a formula that checks column one and then searches column two (twice) for two matches and returns a value which allows me to understand which scenario each ISBN is in.  does it have no files one file but not the other or no files.

Comment: I would create a conditional format that will highlight those items in the first column that doesn't have a corresponding item in the second column.  Look at the `FIND` and `INDEX` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably create two additional columns.  In one column create a flag if there is a text file and in the other a flag if there is a cover.  The formula would look like this if you column with extensions is column B.  These cells would go in row 2 and would be copied down.

They will return the number of cells with the text that matches the ISBN number with -text.pdf added to the end

In the text column column `=countif(b:b,a2&"-text.pdf")`

In the cover column column `=countif(b:b,a2&"-cover.pdf")`

Comment: This solution worked quite well.  I even added onto it by deriving the sum total of those two columns and returning a value of true if it had both components, print if only had text, and cover if the cover was there based on the results of the first formula.  Thanks again, I would upvote if I had the reputation points.